# Run Embedded TomEE 7.1.5 with Gradle

Tags: gradle, apache-tomee, tomee-7

how I can get the deployment into an embedded TomEE?

I used the [CalculatorWs example](https://github.com/apache/tomee/tree/tomee-7.1.5/examples/simple-webservice) and ported it to Gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.apache.tomee.gradle:tomee-embedded:7.1.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.apache.tomee.tomee-embedded'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile 'org.apache.tomee:javaee-api:7.0-2'

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.0'
    testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.23.1'
    testImplementation 'org.apache.tomee:openejb-cxf:7.1.4'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

But now I wonder. The `CalculatorTest` works fine with the `javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer`. I want to deploy the created war into the embedded Tomee?

[image]

How can I tell gradle to deploy the war into the classpath of the embedded Tomee which starts greate with `gradle tomee-embedded -i`?

Thanks,
Markus

Comment: TomEE 7.1.5 is an absolutely ancient version of TomEE, and it probably has security vulnerabilities. I would recommend giving this a try with the latest version in the 8.0.x series, which at the time of this writing is 8.0.12

Answer (score 0):

did you try configuring `tomeeembedded` section with `classpathAsWar=true` or other options? By default it just starts an empty tomee. Options are linked (maven as reference) on https://tomee.apache.org/latest/docs/developer/tools/gradle-plugins.html.

The side note is that the gradle plugin is no more compatible with last gradle versions (which changed its plugin API) so you can also just 1. add tomee-embedded in your buildscript dependencies and 2. write a custom task starting the container (`new Container(new Configuration())`) to replace the plugin.